# How to reload "url" every second using React

Tags: reactjs

I want to reload URL every 5 seconds. Below is my code. What do I do wrong? Please let me know is there anything important point which I missed.

```js
class RandomImg extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { image: "https://picsum.photos/100" };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.imgID = setInterval(() => {
      this.tickImg();
    }, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.imgID);
  }
  tickImg() {
    this.setState({ image: "https://picsum.photos/100" });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>This is Random IMG:</h4>
        <img src={this.state.image}></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working , are you facing any problem?

Comment: make setInterval 1000 to 5000 for 5 seconds

Comment: yes..!! it's working but not changing the image..!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58641351/6544460

Comment: if you are facing any issue , let me know and check posted solution in which i changed image

Comment: it's working but not as expected, it needs to be continuously changed..!!

Comment: you can check now it's working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image URL is not changing and thus the component is not being updated.

Try this

```js
class RandomImg extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { image: "https://picsum.photos/100" };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.imgID = setInterval(() => {
      this.tickImg();
    }, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.imgID);
  }
  tickImg() {
    this.setState({ image: "https://picsum.photos/100?" + Math.random() });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>This is Random IMG:</h4>
        <img src={this.state.image}></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Damir Kasipovic.!!

Comment: You're welcome :) If this answer helped you, consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

```
class RandomImg extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { image: "https://picsum.photos/100" };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.imgID = setInterval(() => {
      this.tickImg();
    }, 5000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.imgID);
  }
  tickImg() {
  this.setState({
  image: `https://picsum.photos/${Math.floor(Math.random()*100)}`
});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>This is Random IMG:</h4>
        <img src={this.state.image}></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You URL is not changing on the tick so the state remains the same. Try adding some random string into the URL

for e.g.

```
tickImg() {
    this.setState({random: this.state.random++ } , () => {
      this.setState({ image: "https://picsum.photos/100?r=" + this.state.random });
})

  }
```